# gphoto2 and crontab

Tags: cron

Thanks in advance for the help I am completely new to all off this. I have a raspberry pi 2 running gphoto2 which I can work and crontab which I can kind of work.

I am looking to make crontab control gphoto2 to take photos and download them between 7 and 7 Monday to Friday for a timelapse.

also can crontab boot and shutdown the pi.

Sorry if this is basic stuff and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about gphoto2, but I do know about cron.  The easiest will be to type  this command in your terminal:

```
$ crontab -e
```

It will show you the following options

```
Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/ed
  2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  3. /usr/bin/vim.basic
  4. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Choose 1-4 [2]: 2
```

Select 2, because Nano is a rather newbie friendly editor.

A line in crontab consists of 6 fields, in order "Minutes", "Hours", "Day of the month", "Month", "Day of the week" and finally "Command to execute".

For more detail, read [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview).  Looks complicated, but once you get the hang of it, it's rather easy.

Your scenario would need a line like this

```
*/5 7-19 * * MON-FRI /full/path/to/command
```

This will run `/full/path/to/command` every 5 minutes (`*/5`), from 7h to 19h (`7-19`), on Monday to Friday (`MON-FRI`).  A single`*` pretty much means "doesn't matter`

Save the file by typing `Ctrl-O` followed by `Enter`, and exit the editor by typing `Ctrl-X`.

I tried this with a command that writes to the syslog (`/usr/bin/logger -t Test "Crontab here!"`) and it works.

Do note this is a "personal" crontab, per user.  There is also a system crontab that has a few more fields.  Start off with this one, should suffice for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got the cron to work on the basic line command like at 5 o clock on friday carry out a reboot of the the pi and it worked its the command part i am stuck on. To trigger the camera with gphoto2 i have to use  "gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download" is this my command or do I have write this somewhere and save it and point the cron to were its saved.

Comment: I'll have to check how gphoto works, but since it's prefixed with 'g', I think that it needs access to the graphical subsystem.  Try finding a command line alternative that doesn't require a GUI.  Alternatively, set your DISPLAY variable in for your cron environment. I'll try to do it later when I'm back on a computer.

Comment: I tried gphoto on my laptop.  It doesn't work with my webcamer.  However gphoto is indeed a pure CLI tools, so if you camera is supported then it should work.  Do use full paths in for programs in the crontab.  Make sure that the target folder has the correct write rights.

If it works from your CLI and you get results, it will work in a crontab.  Since it doesn't work on my laptop, I cannot test further.

Comment: This here works for me.  I had to install the `streamer` package:  `/usr/bin/streamer -c /dev/video0 -f jpeg -o /home/jorg/Pictures/\`date +%F@%T\`.jpeg`

Comment: Thanks again, I have written a script now for the Gphoto to carry out the tasks and have tested it and it works fine from terminal.                                       My script is saved in "/home/pi/timelapse.sh" and when I write the cron to take a photo at example 23:30 I wrote the following in crontab -e                "30 23 * * * /home/pi/timelapse.sh but no joy. I think i am missing a part of the command or saving the sh in the wrong place.

Comment: A typical pitfall is that PATH is not set when running a cron.  What I suggest you do is the following.  Use the following command:  `/home/pi/timelapse.sh 2>&1 >> /home/pi/timelapse.log`.  A little breakdown `2>&1` means, redirect errors to standard out (basically normal output).  The part `>> /home/pi/timelapse.log` means, append everything written to the standard out to the file called  `/home/pi/timelapse.log`.  Go look at this log file to get information on what really happens.  My bet: a command cannot be executed because the system doesn't know where it is, due to lack of PATH.

Comment: I am sometimes getting all white images due to the camera not having enough time to detect exposure. Anyone know a workaround?